# How to delete a row of report using vba in MS-Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How to delete some of rows that containing specific word, from report (not from original database) using vba?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a **query** as the Record Source for your Report, and using appropriate selection criteria in the query to omit the relevant records from the query output.

Since you wish to:

> *delete some of rows that containing specific word*

I would suggest using a `not like` expression within your `where` clause, for example:

```
not like "*word*"
```

Where `word` is the specific word that you wish to exclude.

This way, the records will not be displayed by the Report and are also not deleted from your database, achieving the desired result.